# No desktop after installing graphic drivers?

Tags: drivers, 12.04, graphics

I've installed Ubuntu 12.04 with Wubi. After installing graphic drivers when I reboot and log back in all I can see is black background and cursor isn't moving (but right-click is working), Unity launcher is absent. I tried 3-5 times without any luck.

So, how can I reinstall/repair Ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 0):

Just log in, then right-click your mouse, then click change background, then click the all settings tab, then click Additional Drivers, then uninstall your video driver. Then reboot.